# cannot push to remote repo with personal access token ubuntu/zorin

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

OS: zorin

I cloned a public repo by using ssh `git clone git@github.com:Organization_Name/Repo_Name.git`
Then I created a branch and tried to push to repo by using `git push --set-upstream origin My_Branch`

I got prompt for username and password

```
Username for 'https://github.com': qingqing0226
Password for 'https://qingqing0226@github.com': My_Token
```

Note: I gave all permissions when generating the token so there is no scope issue I guess.
Then I got the error:

```
remote: Permission to Organization_Name/Repo_Name.git denied to qingqing0226.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Organization_Name/Repo_Name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I tried to push many times and always got the same error message. It seems the password(token) is incorrect but I pasted it in txt file to check it and it is correct (no extra space in the end).

**Update: the above error is gone after I used ssh.**

The result of `git config -l`:

```
user.email=My_Email
user.name=qingqing0226
user.password=My_Token
credential.helper=store
url.git@github.com:.insteadof=https://github.com/
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:Organization_Name/Repo_Name.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main
```

**update: I set ssh key and pushed again and got new error:**

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.121.4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
ERROR: Permission to Organization_Name/Repo_Name.git denied to qingqing0226.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It seems I'm not allowed to access the repo

**Last update: I fixed it!!! It turns out that there is nothing wrong with my ssh, token, OS,or anything else. I created a fork and everything is solved.**

Comment: Probably your token doesn't have the appropriate scopes (or you don't have the appropriate permission) to push to this repo.

Comment: Side note: the `OS: Zorin` mention makes sense, but `bash: zsh` doesn't. Perhaps you mean that you use zsh as your shell. In this particular case that doesn't matter, though. If you can use ssh instead of https access, I find this much easier to deal with; the tokens that GitHub likes are difficult to copy (even with cut-and-paste it's easy to get errors here).

Comment: @torek I used ssh instead, and got a new error: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: @AaronBrager I gave all permission (checking all boxes) when generating the token, so I guess scope is not a problem.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the appropriate permission to push to this repo then. Do you own it?

Answer (score 0):

> I created a fork and everything is solved.

That means you were trying to push (through HTTPS or SSH, does not matter) to a repository you did now own, or where you were not a [collaborator](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository).

This differs from a [fork](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/about-forks)

> A fork is a copy of a repository that *you* manage.

Since you own the fork, you can push to it without any issue.